# Laravel with VueJS returns 404 when typing link and refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I tried building a Laravel VueJS application for our POC (Proof of Concept). I already put `vue-router` into the project. It is also already working. But when I try to go to a specific page defined in the routes of the `app.js`, it returns me a `404 error`. Also, when I try doing the regular navigation which involves clicking buttons and refreshing the page to check for my changes, it also gives me a 404. How can I possibly fix this? Thanks for the help. Been stuck for almost half a day already.

Here is my app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from './App.vue';
import Example from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import CampaignList from './components/admin/campaign-list.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const routes = [{
    name: 'Example',
    path: '/',
    component: Example
}, {
    name: 'CampaignList',
    path: '/campaigns',
    component: CampaignList
}];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });
console.log(router);
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Not very familiar with vue, but what do you see when debugging. The routes should map somewhere/return something. Does it get there?

Comment: What version of Vue are you using? The way you're registering the router with Vue doesn't look right to me. It should be using `new Vue({router}).$mount('#app');` but this could be the version I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated a project with your code. And it seems to be working fine.

One thing I would say is, are you trying the right path?

Are you visiting below?

```
http://localhost:8080/campaigns
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/#/campaigns
```

If yes, then try checking the log if you code compiles okay.